# file_get_contents with X-Auth

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm having problems using `file_get_contents` when the URL I'm getting contents from uses X-AUTH authentication. I do have a X-AUTH token but I'm not really sure how to tie it in to `file_get_contents`. As a result of this I get an error when visiting the page in the browser, part of which is:

Warning: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

I've never had many dealings with `file_get_contents` nevermind using it with X-AUTH so I'm a bit stuck!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt you can use `file_get_contents()` to do this, take a look here instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187462/sending-auth-in-headers-php-curl

Answer (score 1):

Please read the foloowing blog post:

[**Using Authentication And file_get_contents()**](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/using-authentication-and-filegetcontents)

The blog entry contains a good example on how to achieve this:

```
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    )
));
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```