# php rest curl authentication header items missing

Tags: php, rest, curl, http-headers, authorization

I'am trying to send via curl a rest request with a header consisting of authorization key and api key.

Therefore I build following curl call:

```
$api_key = 'abc';
$token = 'xyz';


$authorization = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token;
$api = 'Api_key: ' . $api_key;

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authorization, $api));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); // Detail information for debugging
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Debugging the header on the server side shows a header collection with:

```
expect (array)
accept (array)
host (array)
authorization (array)
```

A closer look to the authorization array shows that there is only one item.
This is the value of the authorization key from the client.
The second value, the api_key is missing in the header/authorization array.

Request_header of the client shows, Api_key is available:

```
Host: localhost
Authorization: Basic RG9yaXMgS3JhenM6S3JhdXMxMDAw
Accept: */*
Api_key: abc
Content-Length: 458
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------224938f738738f42
```

Why is the server not able to recieve the full http header authentication information, which is build on an array.
Development environment is apache, php 7, yii, phpstorm.

Comment: How are you checking/debugging the headers on the server side to get that result? Have you checked if there's anything installed on the server that clears custom headers?

Comment: I'am debugging with xdebug and phpstorm. Basically there is nothing installed on the apache server which is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem with putting the API key as 'x-api-key' in the HTTP Header.

This looks like the following code:

```
$api_key = 'abc';
$token = 'xyz';

$authorization = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token;
$api = 'x-api-key: ' . $api_key;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authorization, $api));
```